# What is the meaning of the term "herbert" in British slang?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, british-english, slang

In the song *Get Out of My House* by The Business, the chorus is:

> Out, out get out of my house, you'd better take your sheepskin too
>   no son of mine's going round as a hippie
>   or a scruffy little herbert like you.

What does the term *herbert* mean?

I found this definition [here](http://www.peevish.co.uk/slang/h.htm), but it doesn't make sense to me in the context of the song:

> Noun. An dull objectionable person. E.g. "He's a real herbert, he watches the news and weather on TV all day."

Comment: My dad regularly uses the expression "playing silly herberts" synonymously with "messing around", although I think it might be his invention. He was born in Taunton to a Cockney-ish father and a Guildfordian mother in 1963, and spent a lot of his childhood in Camberley, Surrey, if that means anything to anyone.

Comment: "Little herberts". Heard this yesterday as applied to inmates of local borstal; a parent at work described it as applying to mischevous child (Surrey).

Comment: Just watched the Americas cup on Youtube (race 13) where the commentator called a snagged sheet (rope pulling a sail) a Herbert. I have not found any other reference to its use in this way elsewhere.... Sounds good though.

Comment: Growing up in Surrey during the 70s/80s my dad regularly called me a Herbert/spotty little Herbert/'orrible little Herbert etc, and I now do the same with my two sons. He grew up in south London so may have its origins there. Its always been used as a very mild derogatory term but with affection attached - the sort of language you use when your little darlings have been playing with your car wing mirrors, or get covered in mud, or such like. Another cultural reference nobody has yet mentioned: Arctic Monkeys - Favourite Worst Nightmare album - D is for Dangerous, opening verse - "The dirty lit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've looked up the entry in several slang dictionaries and there seem to be at least two meanings.

- When applied to **children**, that of **silly** and **poorly educated** with a whiff of **mischievousness**.
- When applied to **adults**, that of **foolish** and/or **ridiculous**.

Below are my sources, cited *in extenso*.

**Oxford Dictionary of Slang** (1998)

> **’erbert** n British
> A foolish person, a cheeky, unwashed
> child. For many years, in London working-class slang, *Herbert* or *’Erbert* was
> used to refer to any otherwise unnamed
> man or boy. Gradually, probably by
> being used in phrases such as ‘silly
> ’erbert’, it came to have the more pejorative sense. There probably never was
> an eponymous Herbert; it was merely a common working-class name from the
> Edwardian era.

**The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English** (2008)

> **herbert** noun
>  **1.** a mischievous child or youth. Quite often heard as
> ‘little herbert’ UK, 1999.
>  
>  **2** a harmless youth; a ridiculous man. An
> extension of the previous sense UK, 1960. 
>  **3** a man in a specified field of endeavour UK, 1956

**John Ayto Oxford Dictionary of Slang** (1998)

> **Herbert** (1960) British;
>  applied to a
> foolish or ridiculous man ; arbitrary use of the male forename
> *T. Barling: A dozen baby-brained herberts looking to face me off just to say they squared up to Kosher Kramer before the cobbles came up a bit smartish.*
> (1986)

Comment: I'm totally with "unwashed child". I use the term "smelly 'erbert" which may have come from my Gran who grew up in the East End (of London).

Answer (score 8):

My father used to use the phrase *you 'orrible little 'erberts* quite often. In my neighbourhood it was a fairly common epithet.

It was certainly meant to be derogatory but it was about the mildest level of abuse imaginable. It implies mischief or naughtiness, not diminished mental abilities. It certainly does not mean dull. *Rascal* or *scallawag* might be close synonyms.

Comment: According to Green's *Dictionary of Slang*, *Herbert* means "a simple person". But I don't think that's right. When I use the expression *Herbert*, I mean a moderately ill-behaved boy, one who plays knock-down ginger rather than one who shoplifts, for example. Thus, I agree with Kevin Lawrence.

Answer (score 6):

Oi!

All the answers regarding "old English" usage are correct. However the key here is in the use in a song by The Business who were/are a key pillar of the 80s Skinhead Oi music movement. The term "Herbert" was used to describe those who were not punks or skinheads. It is (as per the original meaning) meant to be slightly derogatory but not at the same level as calling someone a hippie or a BOF (boring old fart). Herberts are tolerated but not admired. Oi Oi Oi.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Toy Dolls dedicated one of their fine early albums to (inter alia) "all the Herberts," which seemed very sporting of them.

Answer (score 5):

According to this [site of Cockney slang](http://www.thornton-cleveleys.co.uk/cockney.htm), a slang definition for *herbert* is:

> **Herbert** -  a foolish person

This [site](http://www.londonslang.com/db/h/) agreed, adding that the term is

> used to describe a foolish person or as a mild form of abuse. Normally prefixed by 'spotty'.

This would make sense in context of the lyrics, since the singer would be saying

> No son of mine will be a hippie... or a scruffy little fool like you

Comment: "as a mild form of abuse" seems to be the relevant part of the second definition.

Answer (score 5):

Growing up just north of London in the late 70s a "little erbert" was the sort of kid likely to nick stuff from the local shop or vandalize a phone box, probably looked like a skinhead (as a lot of kids did at that time). I think this meaning fits the context of the song a lot better. eg "oi, which one of you little erberts smashed my window.."

Answer (score 0):

"Herbert" is a mild form of abuse meaning a silly, or dim-witted person. The origin of this term seems to be that it was derived from the name Herbert, which meant "bright." It was used in the very direct opposite, to mean dumb.

> I found this definition here, but it doesn't make sense to me in the context of the song:

It makes sense, as he is calling the person a "dim-witted person". He says "My son is not going round as a hippie(weirdo) or as a dim-witted person, which you are"

Comment: Once again, I'm asking for evidence of the derivation you propose. That "Herbert" comes from the name is not in doubt, but I simply don't believe that the original meaning of "Herbert" (Her-beorht = "army bright") is in any way connected, simply because in 1925 (which was when the OED first records the word in that sense) this meaning had not been evident in nearly a thousand years. I believe that the reason is that even by the 1920's the name "Herbert" had acquired connotations of being a but dull and slow.

Answer (score 0):

Huh. As an American, the only use of "Herbert" as an insult that I ever heard was from the original Star Trek series, where a group of futuristic hippies use the word as an insult for Captain Kirk. Later Spock tells them, "I am not Herbert", which apparently is the future equivalent of "I'm cool, bro".